# Galois sub-extensions of a Kummer extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let we have the following tower of extensions: $K \subset L \subset M$, where $L,M$ are Galois over $K$ and $L$ contains all roots of unity of degree $n = \left[M:L\right]$, $Gal(M/L)$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, i.e. $M$ is a Kummer extension.

Is the following claim valid?

> If $F \supset K$ is a Galois sub-extension of $M$ then $F \subseteq L$

If yes, could anybody give me a hint how to prove it? If not, could somebody provide me a counter-example?

Comment: I assumed that one: $K \subset F \subseteq L$. I.e. all Galois subextensions should be contained in $L$

Comment: $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q(i) \subset \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb Q(i,\sqrt[4]{2})$. All extensions are Galois over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @MooS Thank you, there is a counter example that I requested

Comment: You mean $M/L$ is a Kummer extension. And to generalize what Moos said : If $L = K(\zeta_n), M = L(\sqrt[n]{a})$, $F = L(\sqrt[d]{a})$ where $d | n$ then $L/F/M/K$ is a tower of Galois extensions, and $L/F/M$ is a tower of Kummer extensions

Comment: @user1952009, yes $M/L$ is a Kummer, extension. BTW I've got the answer that my claim is invalid and also got a counter example

Comment: But the answer  of @user1952009  gives you your counter example if $n$ is not prime